# Laravel doubles the route when navigating between navbar links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-routing

I have a problem with laravel routes. I have a navbar with the urls `/products` and `/employee`.
I manage to switch between perfectly perfectly without giving error. However, when I access the link `/products/new` and from there I try to go back to `/products` or go to `/employees` through the navbar, the link is `/products/products` or `/employee/employee`. How do I not replicate the links?

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/products', 'ControllerProduct@index');
Route::get('/products/new', 'ControllerProduct@create');    
Route::post('/products', 'ControllerProduct@store');    
Route::get('/products/show/{id}', 'ControllerProduct@show');    
Route::get('/products/delete/{id}', 'ControllerProduct@destroy');
Route::get('/products/edit/{id}', 'ControllerProduct@edit');
Route::post('/products/{id}', 'ControllerProduct@update');
```

**app.blade**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <style>
            body {
                padding: 20px;
            }
            .card {
                padding: 20px;
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
                margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <title>Products</title>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> 
            @component('componente_navbar', ["current"=>$current])
            @endcomponent
            <main role="main">
                @hasSection('body')
                    @yield('body')
                @endif
            </main>           
        </div>

        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.blade**

```
@extends('layout.app', ["current"=>"home"])

@section('body')
@endsection
```

**producs.blade**

```
@extends('layout.app', ["current"=>"products"])

@section('body')
<h5 class="card-title">Product Registration</h5>
<div class="card border">
    <div class="card-body">        
        @if(count($products)>0)
            <table class="table table-ordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Título</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($products $pro)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$pro->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$pro->titulo}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/products/show/{{$pro->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Show</a>
                                <a href="/products/edit/{{$pro->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
                                <a href="/products/delete/{{$pro->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="/products/new" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button">New Products</a>
    </div>    
</div>
@if (session('status'))
    <br>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
@endsection
```

**new_products.blade**

```
@extends('layout.app', ["current"=>"products"])

@section('body')
<h4>Products Registration</h4>
<div class="card border">
    <form action="/products" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title_product">Titulo:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title_product" required>
            <br>
            <label for="cod_product">Código:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cod_product" pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{1}"  placeholder="Ex.: 000-000-0" required>
            <br>
            <label for="date_product">Data:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date_product" pattern="\d{2}/\d{/}/\d{4}"  placeholder="Ex.: dd/mm/aaa" required>
            <br>
            <label for="value_product">Valor:</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="value_product" step="0.01" required>
            <br>            
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Ok</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

**componente_navbar.blade**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark rounded">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a @if($current=="home") class="nav-link active" @else class="nav-link" @endif aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a @if($current=="projects") class="nav-link active" @else class="nav-link" @endif href="projects">Projects</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a @if($current=="employees") class="nav-link active" @else class="nav-link" @endif href="employees">Employees</a>
          </li>          
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show the code on how you are calling the routes in your html/blade

Comment: Code, code, code, code. Please show us some code. Route file, and blade file.

Comment: Sorry. Already edit.

Comment: Share code for componente_navbar.blade.php.

There must be issue in urls that you used for anchor tags in this file "componente_navbar.blade.php".

Make sure you are using url function
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url

Or use relative paths like
/products
/employees

Comment: None of the code you have added has anything to do with `navbar` links which is where you issue is according to your post. Please add the code which displays your `navbar`.

Comment: Already added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you have specified your `href` values on your `a` links, they are all defined as relative to the current path:

```
<a ... href="employees" />
```

What the above says is; from where I am currently, take me to the `employees` page. If you're at the root (`/`) of your application then the path is `/employees`. However, if you are anywhere else, the path is `/you-are-here/employees`.

What you really want to do is use one of the [Laravel URL helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#urls-method-list) such as [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url) or [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route).

I personally favour the `route` helper as it uses the name you have defined for a route meaning if the path for a given route changes, you only need to change it in your `web.php` file and don't have to go searching your code base for instances of `/some/path/used/everywhere/`.

You define a name for your route on the route definition in your `web.php` file, so for example:

```
Route::get('/products', 'ControllerProduct@index')->name('products.index');
```

With a name defined (they must be unique by the way), you can use the name in conjunction with the `route()` helper:

```
<a ... href="{{ route('products.index') }}">Projects</a>
```

Now it doesn't matter how deep you are in your site structure, your link will always take you to `/products`.

On a side note, seeing as you appearing to be doing CRUDDY operations, you might want to consider using the `resource` method available on `Route`. This defines all your common routes and their names for you.

```
Route::resource('/products', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('/employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

Note that these assume you're following naming conventions. So rather than `/products/new` it's `/products/create` and your controllers as named `{Something}Controller`. Follow framework conventions where possible, it will save you and other headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Can show you the navbar ?
Maybe it's because you redefine the value of the variable $current every time you extend "layout.app".
If in your return links in your navbar you use the value of the variable $current, by redefining them in each blade the values will be changed.

Another remark you should use the following syntax for your href:
For the new Product for exemple

```
<a href="{{ url('/products/new') }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button">New Products</a>
```

It ensures that your links work in any environment.